# Trying to get text to move in a wave, but it's not working

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to get text that says "Hey there!" to move in a sort of wavy fashion, similar to what you might see in an RPG. Here's the css I'm working with:

```css
.wiggly span {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 90px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-animation: wiggle 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
}
@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    20% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }

    40% {
        transform: translateY(10px);
    }

    60% {
        transform: translateY(10px);
    }

    80% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wiggly">
            <span style="--i:1;">H</span>
            <span style="--i:2;">e</span>
            <span style="--i:3;">y</span>
            <span style="--i:4;">&nbsp;</span>
            <span style="--i:5;">t</span>
            <span style="--i:6;">h</span>
            <span style="--i:7;">e</span>
            <span style="--i:8;">r</span>
            <span style="--i:9;">e</span>
            <span style="--i:10;">!</span>
        </div>
```

I adapted my code off of [this](https://codepen.io/erinesullivan/pen/ZMreqJ) code example and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1ZKHPbnyjo) youtube video. Any idea where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: display:inline-block to span element

Comment: and you can remove the webkit prefixes, it's no more needed

Comment: It worked, thank you!! Why is it that it has to be displayed as inline-block to work?

Comment: read the duplicate for more details

Comment: Will do, thanks again!